# Play Services collision with react-native-maps and react-native-firebase

Tags: google-maps, firebase, react-native, gradle

I'm currently trying to code an application with React Native
In this application I want to use `Google Maps` and `Firebase`, so I add the npm package `react-native-maps` and `react-native-firebase`.

I have setup the packages using the provided documentation.

Now, when I want to compile, I get this error:

```
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':react-native-maps:compileDebugAidl' property 'importDirs' during up-to-date check.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 11.8.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

The problem is, if I correctly understand, that `react-native-maps` needs `google-play-services` in version 10.8.0 and `react-native-firebase` needs `google-play-services` in version 15.0.1

My dependencies in build.gradle (I have tried lots of different version):

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompatv7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.8.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0"
}
```

Thanks by advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**
You can add this code right at the bottom of your `build.gradle`

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

This will disable the google services check. 
It's not optimized but according to this [issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1155) some users had no other choices.

**Option 2:**

Add the ext section to your `build.gradle`

```
ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion   = "15.0.1"
}
```

[source](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1155#issuecomment-426824715)